# How to create a List<GroupEntity> from a List<Entity> using stream?

Tags: java, java-stream

I'm receiving a List of Entity, I need to group them by 2 fields (periodMonth and periodYear) and return as a new list.

To store the groups, I created a class GroupEntity.

The fields that I must use to group doesn't belong to the Entity itself, but to an embeddable class called EntityPK.

Here's the code of these classes:

Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Entity")
public class Entity {

    @EmbeddedId
    private EntityPK entityPk;

    @Column
    private String someValue;
```

EntityPK

```
@Embeddable
public class EntityPK {

    @Column
    private String periodMonth;

    @Column
    private String periodYear;
```

Group class

```
public class GroupOfEntity {

    private String periodMonth;

    private String periodYear;

    private List<Entity> entities;
```

I could iterate over that list and create a map with periodMonth/Year as key, and the List as values, like this:

```
Set<GroupEntity> listOfGroupEntity = new HashSet<GroupEntity>();
        for(Entity entity: listOfEntity) {
            GroupEntity groupEntity = new GroupEntity();
            groupEntity.setPeriodMonth(entity.getEntityPk().getPeriodMonth());
            groupEntity.setPeriodYear(entity.getEntityPk().getPeriodYear());
            Optional<GroupEntity> findFirst = listOfGroupEntity.stream().filter(a -> a.equals(groupEntity)).findFirst();
            if(findFirst.isPresent()) {
                findFirst.get().getEntities().add(entity);
            }else {
                listOfGroupEntity.add(groupEntity);
            }
        }
```

But how could I do that using stream?

Something like

```
List<GroupEntity> groupEntities 
    = listOfEntities.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Entity::getEntityPk::getPeriodMonth,Entity::getEntityPk::getPeriodYear)
```

And create GroupEntity object for each group, with these entities.

Is it possible?

Comment: Wouldn’t doing this in the database be better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Assuming* that `EntityPK` implements `equals` and `hashCode`, you first build `Map<EntityPK, List<Entity>>`, then map that to `List<GroupOfEntity>`.

*Assuming* `GroupOfEntity` has appropriate constructor, you'd do it like this:

```
List<GroupOfEntity> groupEntities = listOfEntities.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Entity::getEntityPk))
        .entrySet().stream()
        .map(e -> new GroupOfEntity(e.getKey().getPeriodMonth(),
                                    e.getKey().getPeriodYear(),
                                    e.getValue()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

First, do this:

```
 Map<EntityPK, List<Entity>> groupEntities =
 entities.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Entity::getEntityPk));
```

And then create GroupOfEntity from the above Map. These two steps can be combined as well.

This is the combined step to further `stream` the map and create `GroupOfEntity`:

```
List<GroupOfEntity> groupEntities
        = entities.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Entity::getEntityPk)).entrySet()
        .stream().map(e -> new GroupOfEntity(e.getKey().getPeriodMonth(), e.getKey().getPeriodYear(), e.getValue()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Please refer the full running sample at [github](https://github.com/fiveobjects/reference/blob/master/java/misc/src/main/java/org/openapex/samples/misc/stream/GroupEntity57226854.java)

Comment: I tested both your and @Andreas solution, and both worked! Since he answered first, ill mark his answer.